# Setting axis title and adding values to the bar

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I need to change the properties (like size of font) of the title axis (circled in red)
[image]

I'm using the apache-poi library and here's the part of the code which generates both titles

```
                XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                bottomAxis.setTitle("Client Name");
                XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
                leftAxis.setTitle("Value ("+clientDataObjectRequest.getDataFormatCodeValue()+")");
                leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
                leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);
```

I've already tried to use the method getOrAddTextProperties().setFontSize() but this change only the size of the labels (client names and numbers) and not the title itself.

In yellow, I would like to add the precisely number of the value. For example, the value of "client 3" is 53,78, so I need to put this value in the chart just after the end of the bar (marked as yellow).

Comment: Take a look at the JavaDoc for [`XDDFValueAxis`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFValueAxis.html) it has a lot of good info, you can make use of [`getOrAddTextProperties()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFValueAxis.html#getOrAddTextProperties--) which returns a [XDDFRunProperties](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/text/XDDFRunProperties.html) object on which you can call things like `setFontSize(...)` or `setHighlight(...)` and many more

Comment: @sorifiend as I said, getOrAddTextProperties().setFontSize() works only for the labels. It does not work for the axis title (circled in red).

Comment: For axis titles see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68893190/resizing-legend-and-axis-title-in-a-apache-poi-bar-chart/68948630#68948630. For add data labels see https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3915431%20add%20data%20labels.

Comment: @AxelRichter I think I did not make myself clear: what I meant is a way to put the value at the end of the bar? I mean, at the in each bar, I want to put the value (number) accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question  about formatting the axes titles is answered already. See [Resizing legend and axis title in a apache poi bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68893190/resizing-legend-and-axis-title-in-a-apache-poi-bar-chart/68948630#68948630).

"To add the precisely number of the value" to the data bars means to have data labels set. This is not directly supported ny Apache POI until now. So using low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*` classes is necessary. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3915431%20add%20data%20labels. Of course this is not very comfortable. So I have tried to create a method `void setDataLabels(XDDFChartData.Series series, int pos, boolean... show)` for this.

There `int pos` can be one of the following:

```
INT_BEST_FIT   1 - positions data label at best fit to be readable
INT_B          2 - positions data label at bottom
INT_CTR        3 - positions data label at center
INT_IN_BASE    4 - positions data label inside at base
INT_IN_END     5 - positions data label inside at the end
INT_L          6 - positions data label at left
INT_OUT_END    7 - positions data label outside at the end
INT_R          8 - positions data label at right
INT_T          9 - positions data label at top
```

Not all chart types support all positions.

The `boolean... show` is a list of boolean to tell what shall visible (`true`) or not visible (`false`) in the data labels. Sequence is as follows:

```
ShowVal, ShowLegendKey, ShowCatName, ShowSerName, ShowPercent, ShowBubbleSize, ShowLeaderLines
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.PresetColor;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFShapeProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFSolidFillProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisCrosses;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisCrossBetween;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.BarDirection;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.ChartTypes;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFBarChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFLineChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFPieChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFCategoryAxis;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFValueAxis;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFTitle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/**
 * Bar chart example.
 */
public final class BarChart {
    private BarChart() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        Object[][] chartData = new Object[][]{
            new Object[]{"Client 1", "Client 2", "Client 3", "Client 4", "Client 5", "Client 6", "Client 7", "Client 8"},    
            new Object[]{12, 2.345d, 34, 6, 45.6d, .456d, 50.5d, 12.345d},    
        };
        
        try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("barchart");
            
            // put sheet data
            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            int rowIndex = 0;
            int colIndex = 0;
            for (Object[] dataRow : chartData) {
                row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
                colIndex = 0;
                for (Object value : dataRow) {
                    cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
                    if (value instanceof String) cell.setCellValue((String)value);
                    if (value instanceof Number) cell.setCellValue(((Number)value).doubleValue());
                    colIndex++;
                }
                rowIndex++;
            }
            
            // create the chart
            
            // chart data sources
            XDDFDataSource<String> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, colIndex - 1));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, colIndex - 1));

            // chart in drawing
            XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8, 20);
            XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
            chart.setTitleText("Turnover Rate");
            chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
            chart.getFormattedTitle().getParagraph(0).addDefaultRunProperties().setFontSize(20d);

            // category axis
            XDDFCategoryAxis catAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            XDDFTitle title = getOrSetAxisTitle(catAxis);
            title.setOverlay(false);
            title.setText("Client Name");
            title.getBody().getParagraph(0).addDefaultRunProperties().setFontSize(12d);

            // value axis
            XDDFValueAxis valAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
            title = getOrSetAxisTitle(valAxis);
            title.setOverlay(false);
            title.setText("Value (Percentage)");
            title.getBody().getParagraph(0).addDefaultRunProperties().setFontSize(12d);
 
            // cross axes 
            valAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
            valAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

            // chart data
            XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, catAxis, valAxis);
            // series
            XDDFChartData.Series series1 = data.addSeries(xs, ys1);
            series1.setTitle("Series 1", null); // there must be a series title even if no legend is needed
            // add data labels
            setDataLabels(series1, 7, true); // pos 7 = INT_OUT_END, showVal = true
            
            // plot chart
            chart.plot(data);

            // in order to transform a bar chart into a column chart, you just need to change the bar direction
            XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
            // bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.COL);

            // set series fill color
            solidFillSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.BLUE);

            // Write the output to a file
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("./ooxml-bar-chart.xlsx")) {
                wb.write(fileOut);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void solidFillSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
        XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
        XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries(index);
        XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
        }
        properties.setFillProperties(fill);
        series.setShapeProperties(properties);
    }
    
    private static XDDFTitle getOrSetAxisTitle(XDDFValueAxis axis) {
        try {
            java.lang.reflect.Field _ctValAx = XDDFValueAxis.class.getDeclaredField("ctValAx");
            _ctValAx.setAccessible(true);
            org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTValAx ctValAx =
                (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTValAx)_ctValAx.get(axis);
            if (!ctValAx.isSetTitle()) {
                ctValAx.addNewTitle();
            }
            XDDFTitle title = new XDDFTitle(null, ctValAx.getTitle());
            return title;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;            
        }
    }

    private static XDDFTitle getOrSetAxisTitle(XDDFCategoryAxis axis) {
        try {
            java.lang.reflect.Field _ctCatAx = XDDFCategoryAxis.class.getDeclaredField("ctCatAx");
            _ctCatAx.setAccessible(true);
            org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTCatAx ctCatAx =
                (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTCatAx)_ctCatAx.get(axis);
            if (!ctCatAx.isSetTitle()) {
                ctCatAx.addNewTitle();
            }
            XDDFTitle title = new XDDFTitle(null, ctCatAx.getTitle());
            return title;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;            
        }
    }
    
    private static void setDataLabels(XDDFChartData.Series series, int pos, boolean... show) {
        /*
        INT_BEST_FIT   1
        INT_B          2
        INT_CTR        3
        INT_IN_BASE    4
        INT_IN_END     5
        INT_L          6
        INT_OUT_END    7
        INT_R          8
        INT_T          9                             
        */
        try {
            org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTDLbls ctDLbls = null;
            if (series instanceof XDDFBarChartData.Series) {
                java.lang.reflect.Field _ctBarSer = XDDFBarChartData.Series.class.getDeclaredField("series");
                _ctBarSer.setAccessible(true);
                org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTBarSer ctBarSer =
                    (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTBarSer)_ctBarSer.get((XDDFBarChartData.Series)series);
                if (ctBarSer.isSetDLbls()) ctBarSer.unsetDLbls();
                ctDLbls = ctBarSer.addNewDLbls();                                                        
                if (!(pos == 3 || pos == 4 || pos == 5 || pos == 7)) pos = 3; // bar chart does not provide other pos
                ctDLbls.addNewDLblPos().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STDLblPos.Enum.forInt(pos));
            } else if (series instanceof XDDFLineChartData.Series) {
                java.lang.reflect.Field _ctLineSer = XDDFLineChartData.Series.class.getDeclaredField("series");
                _ctLineSer.setAccessible(true);
                org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTLineSer ctLineSer =
                    (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTLineSer)_ctLineSer.get((XDDFLineChartData.Series)series);
                if (ctLineSer.isSetDLbls()) ctLineSer.unsetDLbls();
                ctDLbls = ctLineSer.addNewDLbls();                                                      
                if (!(pos == 3 || pos == 6 || pos == 8 || pos == 9 || pos == 2)) pos = 3; // line chart does not provide other pos
                ctDLbls.addNewDLblPos().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STDLblPos.Enum.forInt(pos));
            } else if (series instanceof XDDFPieChartData.Series) {
                java.lang.reflect.Field _ctPieSer = XDDFPieChartData.Series.class.getDeclaredField("series");
                _ctPieSer.setAccessible(true);
                org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPieSer ctPieSer =
                    (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPieSer)_ctPieSer.get((XDDFPieChartData.Series)series);
                if (ctPieSer.isSetDLbls()) ctPieSer.unsetDLbls();
                ctDLbls = ctPieSer.addNewDLbls();                                                      
                if (!(pos == 3 || pos == 1 || pos == 4 || pos == 5)) pos = 3; // pie chart does not provide other pos
                ctDLbls.addNewDLblPos().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STDLblPos.Enum.forInt(pos));
            }// else if ...                                                          
                                                               
            if (ctDLbls != null) {
                ctDLbls.addNewShowVal().setVal((show.length>0)?show[0]:false);
                ctDLbls.addNewShowLegendKey().setVal((show.length>1)?show[1]:false);
                ctDLbls.addNewShowCatName().setVal((show.length>2)?show[2]:false);
                ctDLbls.addNewShowSerName().setVal((show.length>3)?show[3]:false);
                ctDLbls.addNewShowPercent().setVal((show.length>4)?show[4]:false);
                ctDLbls.addNewShowBubbleSize().setVal((show.length>5)?show[5]:false);
                ctDLbls.addNewShowLeaderLines().setVal((show.length>6)?show[6]:false);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }                              
    }          
   
}
```

Result:

[image]